# Publish single Habitat project

Tags: habitat

In Habitat, we have gulp tasks for:

- Publish All Projects
- Publish-Foundation-Projects
- Publish-Feature-Projects
- Publish-Project-Projects

I want to publish a single Project. I can use `msbuild`, as described here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/command-line-deployment - but I'm not sure this will work, as the Gulpfile pulls in config from `gulp-config.js`, and performs tasks such as 'Apply XML transform' and 'Sync unicorn'.

What's the recommended way to publish a single Habitat project?

Comment: Does this need to be done via gulp, or have you tried just right clicking on the project and publishing the project directly?

Comment: I can definitely publish from Visual Studio - there's no problem there. Would this miss out any crucial steps of the build pipeline? I see that Gulp does things like 'Apply XML Transform' and 'Sync Unicorn'

Comment: Nope - @DylanYoung is right - the publish tasks in gulp just do the same as right-click -> publish

Comment: Thanks both. Happy to accept your answer, if you can make it answerable :)

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to write a gulp task to publish and then apply your transforms and/or sync?

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel I think I'm happy with publishing single projects from VS, then running a whole solution publish / sync / transform from Gulp should I have changed config or content (which won't happen very often for my use case).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can publish a single project by right clicking on the project and selecting the `Publish` option in Visual Studio.  Or if you have Click Once publishing toolbar open, you can select the project and publish by clicking the `Publish Web` button.

Typically I will use this process when I am working on a single project, vs waiting for all the projects to complete publishing.